# Where do we set layout value in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, layout

I am eager to know where we set the layout value in joomla. When I used the code

```
$this->input->get('layout', 'edit', 'string');
```

I am getting a value, which I dont know from where it comes. Will it takes value from database or code part itself?
I wrote this code in JControllerForm class, in which I am troubleshooting a layout issue by tracing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code will try to get the layout value from request parameter "layout". If there is no request parameter found, it will use the default value which is "edit". If you want to override the default value, send "layout" parameter as part of your request parameter. It could be a hidden field in your form.